# Connect local Laravel environment to Google Cloud SQL - MySQL

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-sql

I try to connect my Laravel project into my local development environment to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL).

For this, I connected from my OSX Terminal with the Cloud SQL-Proxyclient to the remote database with port 3307.
I can connect with my MySQL Workbench to the remote database, and I can see/change tables, ...

Into my Laravel project into .env I changed the settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=mydatabasename
DB_USERNAME=mydatabaseusername
DB_PASSWORD=mydatabasepassword
```

When I open my project into the browser, into terminal I can't see, that something tries to use the connection.
Into the browser I get an error message: 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (2002)

I think, the project can't connect to the remote database

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have config for right DB_HOST. Let get an IPv4 Read this for more informations:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP

Comment: I added the same IP address, Port, and access datas to the .env as into my MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

While the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) connects to your database on port `3307`, you want to connect to the Cloud SQL proxy on port `3306` (this is the default mysql port). You can also specify a custom port by updating the instances argument:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-project:us-central1:sql-inst=tcp:3306 &
```

Comment: Into config file I saved:
    DB_PORT=3307
you can see it into my config settings above.

Comment: Exactly. The proxy is listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 by default.

Answer (score 1):

I added now the public IP address of the server, and I added my local IP address to allowed IP adresses for the MySQL server. Now it works.